# R markdown code showing output I don't want, how do I remove it?

Tags: r, r-markdown

Hey guys so I'm just trying things out on sentiment analysis however, when I out put my code on R-markdown after knitting, it's showing me the output which includes my graph and the unwanted output circled in red. I only want the bar graph to show.

[image: Code in rmarkdown]

This is the out put I get.

[image]

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Could you give us a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you. I work with R Markdown and ggplot2 a lot and have never seen this.

Comment: is there a '+' missing before `theme` ?

Comment: Turns out I just missed the '+' before the theme. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is coming from the call to theme which is separate to your plot as the `+`-sign is missing after `labs`and before `theme`. Add the `+` and everything will be fine.

*you may recognize that the text of the x axis is has no angle of 45*

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing a comma at the top of your code chunk.

Try:
`{r, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE}`